# Read claims without verification. , Understanding the Result return

Tags: rust, jwt, rust-result

I'm working JWT's in Rust and have come across a situation that I'm having some issues navigating. I'm new to both Rust and JWT's, so bare with me.

I'm using the `jwt` crate found [here](https://crates.io/crates/jwt).

What I want to do is create a Signed JWT that contains a header and claims. The claims have a single field, `issuer`. I'm able to issue a new token with no issue.

```
fn issue_token(user_id: &str) -> Result<String, &'static str> {
    let header: Header = Default::default();
   
    let claims = RegisteredClaims {
        issuer: Some("user who issued token".into()),
        subject: Some(user_id.into()),
        ..Default::default()
    };

    let unsigned_token = Token::new(header, claims);

    let key: Hmac<Sha256> =
        Hmac::new_from_slice("secret_key".as_bytes()).map_err(|_e| "Invalid key")?;

    let signed_token = unsigned_token
        .sign_with_key(&key)
        .map_err(|_e| "Sign error")?;

    Ok(signed_token.into())
}
```

The `issuer` claim is important. As there are different processes that have their own tokens. All of the `issuers` have already registered their `secret` with the main server. Now, other users will connect to a specific `issuer`, validate who the user is, and will issue a JWT that has been signed. The user does not know what the `secret` is, that's only known between the `issuer` and the server.

What I'm trying to do, on the server-side, is read the `claims` to identify who the `issuer` is. Once I know who the `issuer` is I then know what secret to use to verify the signature.

I have no issues verifying the token, and once I verify the token, I'm able to read the claims. But I need to read the claims first, and then verify the token.

beyond the basic examples for signing and verifying, the documentation is clear to me.

looking at the documentation for the crate, [here](https://docs.rs/jwt/0.16.0/jwt/), I've not been able to figure out how to implement what I'm attempting to do.

I've found what I believe to be what I'm looking for, [here](https://docs.rs/jwt/0.16.0/jwt/?search=unverified), `parse_unverified` or `Unverified`, but I'm struggling to figure out how to use either.

`parse_unverified` looks to be the more promising of the two as the documentation states `Not recommended. Parse the header and claims without checking the validity of the signature`

Does anyone have any experience with Rust and the `jwt` crate?

I believe I've gotten it partially figured out.

it starts with importing the correct crate options

```
use jwt::{Claims, Error, Header, RegisteredClaims, Token, Unverified, VerifyWithKey};
```

I can then create a new variable, like

```
let unverified: Result<Token<Header, Claims, Unverified<'_>>, Error> =
            Token::parse_unverified(token);
```

Now this works, it builds and runs just fine. What I'm having an issue with now is actually parsing `unverified` now.

the more that I look at it, I think this might have less to do with JWT and more to do with standard Rust operations. As its returning a `Result`.

Any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a standard `Result`, so you have to unwrap that as usual with `?` to get at the `Token` inside.  Even though this doesn't verify the signature, it can still fail due to invalid base64/JSON encoding or JWT framing.  (If there's an error here the token isn't even structurally valid, so there's no point in going further.)

```
let unverified: Token<Header, Claims, _> = Token::parse_unverified(token)?;
```

Now you can use any facilities provided by [`Token`](https://docs.rs/jwt/0.16.0/jwt/struct.Token.html) on `unverified`, e.g. `unverified.claims()`.

You might want to parse with [`RegisteredClaims`](https://docs.rs/jwt/0.16.0/jwt/claims/struct.RegisteredClaims.html) though, which gives you easier access to the issuer field:

```
let unverified: Token<Header, RegisteredClaims, _> =
    Token::parse_unverified(token)?;

let issuer = unverified.claims().issuer.as_ref()
    .ok_or(MissingIssuerError)?;
```

`issuer` will be a `&String`.  (`MissingIssuerError` is a placeholder for an error you can raise if the issuer field is absent.)